# Why does my website's HTTPS say it's outdated?

Tags: apache, security, https, verification

My website has a warning on its HTTPS security settings. Chrome tells me that it "does not have public audit records" and "The site is using outdated security settings".

Firefox tells me "This website does not supply ownership information" in the "Owner" field, and for the "Verified by" field it says "Not specified", even though Chrome is able to detect that it is verified by "DigiCert High Assurance CA-3".

What do I need to do to remove these warnings, update my settings, and ensure my website is secure? The website is served by apache.

Comment: You're using a 2048 bit key and OCSP but with a sha1 hash? You might want to configure your server to favour more effective algorithms. see also https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=slc.edu

Answer (score 4):

"does not have public audit records" - it means it hasn't been published in append-only *Certificate Transparency* logs. It is a new feature, almost no certificate has it. Nothing to worry about.

"The site is using outdated security settings" - this probably means your certificate contains SHA1 digest. All certificates issued at this time contains more secure SHA256 digest.

"This website does not supply ownership information" - this is shown for *Domain Validated* certificates. It means the certificate request was authorized by domain ownership only. If you use *Extended Validation* certificate, it will show your company's name.

So basically you should request for a new certificate.

Comment: "probably means your certificate contains SHA1 digest" Is there anything else than can cause this?  Is a new private key required or only a new certificate?